# javascript array to list of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a following data, and I want to convert to list of array without key.
How do I do it?

Data

```
[{
    "time": "01/13 15:50",
    "price": 3000,
    "changeRate": -0.27
},
{
    "time": "01/13 15:40",
    "price": 4000,
    "changeRate": -0.27 
}]
```

Desired output

```
 [
    [01/13 15:50, 3000],
    [01/13 15:40, 4000]
  ]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is not JSON in your code. It is a POJO array

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method for that. It's used to transform (or "map") one array into a new one. The new array has the same length as the original, and its items are derived from the items in the original array.

```js
data.map(item => [item.time, item.price]);
```